# Vue 3 - Vuetify 3 : color--text not working

Tags: vue.js, colors, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I've tried to install Vuetify with Vue3 for the first time today. Almost everything is working properly: components are being imported correctly, classes like "text-center" are working well too.

But I've noticed that props like "dark", and classes like "color--text" are not and I can't tell why ...

Here is my plugins/vuetify.js file:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/lib/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

export default createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})
```

For example:

```
<h1 class="display-2 font-weight-bold mb-3">
    <div class="red--text">Welcome to the Vuetify 3 Alpha</div>
</h1>
```

**The text will not be red, nothing changes.**

I have no clue where the problem could come from soo ... This is an S.O.S

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [vuetify classes](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes) It should be  `text-red` instead of `red--text` :

```
 <v-app>
    <div class="bg-purple-darken-2 text-center">
      <span class="text-red">Lorem ipsum</span>
    </div>
  </v-app>
```